# c++ which is of non-class type error

Tags: c++

for the start keep in mind I am a complete rookie in c++. I have read a lot about templates and strings today, but I cant figure couple of things out. When I create a point in my test class with point<2> or any other value. I have an error: request for member 'tostring' in 'v2' which is of non-class type... 
1. Why do I get that error?
2. How can make Point() = default; to make every coordinate value 0.0; Like if I have Point<1> it would be (0.0), Point<2> would be (0.0, 0.0) and so on:.

```
#ifndef POINT_H
#define POINT_H
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using std::stringstream;
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;


template<unsigned short n>
class Point {

public:
    list <float> coords = {0.0};
    Point <n>() = default; 
    Point <n>(list<float> coords){

        this-> coords=coords;
        }

        string toString(){
            string sone;
            ostringstream ss;
            sone.append("(");
            auto it3= coords.begin();
            while ((it3) != coords.end()){  
                ss <<  (*it3);
                sone.append(ss.str());
                ss.str("");
                }
            sone.append(")");
            return sone;
        }

        float distanceFrom (Point <n> v){
            float s=0;
            list<float> coords;
            auto it1= coords.begin();
            auto it2= v.coords.begin();
            while ((it1) != coords.end()){  
                s+=(*it1 -*it2)*(*it1-*it2);
                it1++;
                it2++;
            }
        return sqrt(s);
        }
    friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, const Point<n>& v)
    {
        out << "("<<"Test"<<")";
        return out;
    }
};


#endif
```

Comment: This code compiles fine for me.

Comment: But if you create a point: Point<2> v3 { list<float>{2.0,3.0} }; and try to use: cout << v3.toString () << endl;   then it gets error.              And what if you declare a point like that: Point<2> v1; then using .toString() will give just (), but I want it to give (0.0 , 0.0).

Comment: @user3328230, Inside the class, you don't need to say `Point<n>`, just `Point`. Apart from that, please **never** put using directives or declarations in a header.

Comment: @chris ... at least to specify the constructor methods ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, And anywhere else inside the class definition as well. The only time you need to specify it is when `n` is not the same as the current instantitation's `n`.

Comment: @chris I was thinking about a copy constructor signature for instance. There you need to specify the parameter as `const Point<n>&`, or is this deprecated now? That's a common mistake I've seen often and been asked for ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, You [shouldn't](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fef16529b4bf3717) need it there AFAIK.

Comment: How can I use my toString in ostream& operator?

Comment: can anyone tell me what is wrong with my distanceFrom method. it always gives answer 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increment iterator in a method toString and it works:

```
string toString(){
            string sone;
            ostringstream ss;
            sone.append("(");
            auto it3= coords.begin();
            while ((it3) != coords.end()){  
                ss <<  (*it3);
                sone.append(ss.str());
                ss.str("");
                ++it3;
                ^^^
                }
            sone.append(")");
            return sone;
        }
```

[compiled example](http://ideone.com/UiTThg)

---

The note about templates:

inside the class body you don't need to say `Point<n>`, just `Point`:

```
Point () = default;
Point ( list<float> coords){ //...}
```

---

To print Point you have to make `toString` method `const`:

```
string toString() const { //... }
```

to enable call on a const Point. Now you can use it in `operator<<` :

```
 friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, const Point<n>& v) {
        out << v.toString();
        return out;
 }
```

Comment: True enough, though not the error in the question, which is a compiler error and probably unrelated to what's shown in the question.

Comment: what could it be related to? should I copy the code of test program or?

Comment: How can I use toString in friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, const Point<n>& v)
    {
        out << "("<<"Test"<<")";
        return out;
    } to return the point?

Comment: @user3328230 do you mean to write coordinates to cout? note: this returns ostream& not Point

Comment: I want that if i say cout << v1 << endl; in test program, it would print out (2.3,3.4) for example. The same format as toString. I try to use toString in ostream& operator but dont know how.

Comment: this gives error: request for member `tostring´ in ´v´, which is non-class type 'const int'

Comment: It works, but I still cant get it to work if I try to use it in my test program. Where main is not in header.

Comment: Do you know what is wrong with the distancefrom method why does it return 0.

Comment: main method has to be in .cpp